# Estimate probability of a team winning given the chances of the indivuduals

Tags: probability

Say a team consists of three players, P1, P2, and P3, and each player has their own individual win-rate regardless of the team. Given their history, assume that P1 has an average win-rate of 45%, P2 at 61%, and P3 at 37%.

Given that a team does not have fixed members (meaning the next match could have A P1, P2, and P4 instead), how does this affect the probability of any given game?

Is the probability of this team winning THIS GAME simply (45 + 61 + 37) / 3, or is it more accurate to calculate it using conditional probability?

Comment: This is not an assignment or anything, it's just a sudden thought I had while watching team table tennis. I personally think conditional probability makes more sense than just mere average, but I honestly have no idea

Comment: The formulation is just unclear, if these 3 players are always in one team, then we should have all rates equal, otherwise, the situation can be very complicated, you should state it out.

Comment: When you don't know *anything* else other than their individual win rates, you can't even use conditional expectations, because you don't know how the wins of the individuals depend upon each other - and in that case, the empirical average might be the best estimate you can get. But it might not be a very good estimate: Say the three players have the win-rates 45%, 61% and 0% (so that P3 always loses, no matter what team he is on). Then it would seem that P3 is such a bad player that no matter his team, he brings everyone down with him.

Answer (score 0):

Say there are $N$ players in the squad, whose overall average is $M$.
Then $P1$ contributes $Q1$, and $(Q1+M+M)/3=45\%$, and $Q1=135-2M$.
Likewise $Q2=183-2M$ and $Q3=111-2M$.  So the team with these three has $(Q1+Q2+Q3)/3=143-2M$ chance of winning.
That is, $P1+P2+P3-2M$.
Obviously if $M=50\%$ then the chance would be $P1+P2+P3-100$.